# angular ui-grid render issue on items per page change

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-grid

Here's how i got it:
1. While on the first page, scroll down till you're at the bottom of the grid
2. change "items per page" to 75( assuming it was 25)

I see that the grid becomes blank.

The issue can be observed here (check the demo):http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/214_pagination

Can anyone pls tell me how to resolve this or route me to the solution if it's available here.

Comment: can i show ur code for that?

Comment: pls check the link that I've shared.. the behaviour I've mentioned can be observed there itself. Thanks!

Comment: I saw no such behaviour, do you mind saying what browser are you using?

Comment: Only if i could post images(some reputation points required which i don't have), anyway I'm using IE11, even i checked in chrome.. same issue...

Comment: Looks like a definite bug; this would be better to put in a github issue. (caveat: author here)

Comment: Looks like it's already there: https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/2434

Answer (score 2):

fix suggested in this link works for me: https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/2434

setting the virtualizationThreshold on gridoptions and onRegistedApi

```
scope.gridOptions = {
                                paginationPageSizes : [ 25, 50, 75, 100],
                                paginationPageSize : 25,
                                virtualizationThreshold: 25,

onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
      gridApi.pagination.on.paginationChanged($scope,function(){
        $scope.gridOptions.virtualizationThreshold =  $scope.gridOptions.paginationPageSize;
      })
    }
```

Not sure if this is the ideal solution, but it serves my purpose

However when i change items per page to 1000, i'm seeing performance issues.. it takes quite sometime to render rows..